# Linear Span: question on set theoretic definition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a question regarding interpretation of the set theoretic collectivizing form used for the definition of Linear Span below:

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) defines Linear Span as:

$\mathrm{span}(S) = \{\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i| k \in \mathbb{N}, v_i \in S, \lambda_i \in K\}$

where $K$ is a field and $S$ is the spanning set of the vector space.  **Basically, what does this form say?**  This is my understanding so far.

My understanding of the collectivizing form is that, $\Gamma = \{x | \phi(x) \}$, such that it is collectivizing $x$ when $\phi$ holds.  The above form of the span is confusing with $\Sigma$ ranging in $k$.  I'm not sure if this is even a valid form.

I think $\Sigma$ binds $i$.  Then $k, v_i, \lambda_i$ should be bound during quantification.  For $i = 1$ it seems this will result in multiple values for $\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i$, which confuses me because if $k > 1$ the summation form is only partially complete.  Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: $\text{span}(S)$ is the set of $x\in V$ such that there exist $k\in\Bbb{N}$ and there exist $v_1,\dots, v_k\in S, \lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_k\in K$ for which $x=\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_iv_i$. I'm not sure I understand your remark about $\Sigma$ binding $i$; the letter $i$ has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: The letter $i$ is used both in summation and quantification for the variables?

Comment: The letter $i$ strictly speaking should only be used as the summation index. On the RHS in wikipedia, it is admittedly a little sloppy notation, but because it is expected that the reader be able to understand what is meant (which I explained in my previous comment).

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have a suggestion for the correct notation?  $i$ is bound to scope of the summation, therefore I'm a little lost on it's use in the RHS.

Comment: Maybe $\mathrm{span}(S) = \{\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i| z,k \in \mathbb{N}, z \le k,v_z \in S, \lambda_z \in K\}$?

Comment: @Nick: It’s simply $$\operatorname{span}(S)=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_iv_i:k\in\Bbb Z^+\land\forall i\in[k](v_i\in S\land k_i\in K)\right\}\,;$$ here $[k]=\{1,\ldots,k\}$, a notation common in combinatorics.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks! Your form makes sense.  I think $[k] = \{x | x \le k \land x \in \mathbb{Z^+}\}$.

Comment: @Nick: Whether you can write $[k]$ that way depends entirely on the context. If you’ve established that you’re talking about $Z^+$, the set of positive integers, then you can do that. If the context is $\Bbb N$, the set of non-negative integers, $\Bbb Z$, $\Bbb Q$, or $\Bbb R$, then you cannot. I would accept $[k]=\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:n\le k\}$.